# Making Simple IF Statements Shorter

Tags: programming-practices, language-agnostic, coding-standards, conditions

If we assume we have this little snippet of code:

```
string str = "checked";
bool test1;

if (str == "checked")
{
    test1 = true;
}
else
{
    test1 = false;
}
```

Is it bad practice to change a simple statement like this to the following?:

```
bool test2 = (str == "checked");
```

Because they work exactly the same, and work as required, so I can't imagine how it would be. However, as a young, inexperienced programmer I am not aware of whether such a thing is frowned upon or not. Can anyone tell me, if this is NOT ok, why not?

The following test program:

```
using System;

public class Test
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "checked";

        bool test1;

        if (str == "checked")
        {
            test1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            test1 = false;
        }

        bool test2 = (str == "checked");

        bool test3 = (str != "checked");

        Console.WriteLine(test1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(test2.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(test3.ToString());
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
True
True
False
```

Any insight etc is appreciated.

Comment: personally I'd use the shorter non-if way, suspect this should be migrated to code review though?

Comment: You are on a good path. Next, you can set about eliminating `= some_complicated_condition ? true : false;`s

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the ternary operator evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/is-the-ternary-operator-evil)

Comment: There is a another way:  boolean test4=isChecked(str)  ....                 boolean isChecked(String str){ return "checked"==str; }.  You can use the method name to make this appropriately self-documenting.

Comment: Like @emory suggested, which I wish would be added as answer, wrap it in a function.  It is a distinct query after all.

Comment: It's a good practice. Also, it's like the FizzBuzz test: any programmer who claims boolean expressions are "difficult to understand" and that "gets it backwards" unless "they are spelled out in a 'long-form' if" should be a NO HIRE. Think about it: if they can't handle this complexity, would you trust them with fixing a problem in production?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to change a simple statement like this to the following?:

```
bool test2 = (str == "checked");
```

No, it's good practice. To me, the longer code:

```
if (str == "checked")
{  
    test1 = true;
}
else
{
    test1 = false;
}
```

indicates that the programmer doesn't understand Boolean expressions.  The shorter form is much clearer.  Similarly, don't write:

```
if (boolean-expression) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Just write `return boolean-expression;`

Comment: Ohh, and I love those `if (var == true)` stuff.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: some programmers seem to believe that every if statement needs a relational operator

Comment: +1000 to this answer (if I could). It indeed indicates lack of understanding of boolean expressions. Also, the longer form is _never_ "clearer". No amount of `{`, `}` or `;` will make a simple boolean expression "clearer". Everyone: please stop equating clarity with needless verbosity.

Comment: Awesome! I had a feeling I was right, I just wasn't sure due to my inexperience...

Answer (score 12):

I would be very annoyed at someone who used the long form when the statement is that simple.

It hints that the one who wrote it either doesn't understand boolean data types, or doesn't realize `==` is independent of `if`.

Answer (score 6):

While the shorter form is more elegant and compact, there's an advantage to the long form: You can easily set a breakpoint at `test1 = true`, while you can't with the shorter form.

Comment: this is not true (anymore), Intellij has a conditional breakpoint

Comment: Many modern debuggers do. However, it's definitely more complex that assigning a breakpoint to a line, and has a lower chance of working in the first go.

Answer (score 2):

*Who will see your code?*

If you think that others who might see your code will be confused with one-line `if` statements, then use the full spelled-out version.  Also, if you think that you might accidentally reverse the logic, then spell it out.

Example:
At a previous job, I had coworkers that required the full, spelled out logic.  When they tried to use the one-liners, they would get the logic backwards on a regular basis.  Where I'm at now, the company is filled with intelligent people who would very rarely (if ever) make that mistake.  Here, we nest the ternary `if` statements with no confusion.

Comment: People confused by boolean expressions should be educated. If after being taught about them they are still confused, they have no right to be programmers. But no, the needlessly verbose `if` is never the right answer. (Likewise, you shouldn't stop writing `for each` in Java simply because some inexperienced programmer is still unfamiliar with them).

Comment: PS: I'd be _terribly scared_ of your coworkers who "got the logic backwards". Were there no code reviews? No tests? Did they get fired? Did anyone got fired at your company for incompetence, _at all_?

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  The computer will understand all forms.  So you should write it the way your audience prefers.  @AndresF in some multidisciplinary workspaces, some people from non-technical backgrounds may look at your code

Comment: @emory Sorry, that's simply not true. The only people who should look _at the code_ are the people who can understand it. Never in my career have I seen non-technical people trying to understand source code (as opposed to requirements, diagrams, etc). In any case, my argument is that `return booleanExpr;` is TONS simpler than `if (booleanExpr == true) { return true; } else { return false; }`. It's _hard_ to argue the opposite, even for "non-technical people"; because for them, what do all those extraenous `if`, `{`, `else` and `}` add?

Comment: This is like saying "let's not use scalpels for surgery, because non-surgeons might not understand them. Let's use kitchen knives instead! They are easier, and everyone has them!"

Comment: LOL.  I did mention that it's my *previous* job, right?  I'm glad that you all live sheltered lives away from the throngs of incompetent programmers and inadequate managers.

Answer (score 2):

Answering under the assumption that this boolean statement will always be this simple, I have no doubt that the simplified one-liner:

```
bool test2 = (str == "checked");
```

would be sufficient, and it definitely produces fewer lines of IL. In my experiment with Mono I found the one-line statement produced:

```
IL_0000: ldstr "test"
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: ldstr "test"
IL_000c: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
IL_0011: stloc.1
IL_0012: ldloc.1
```

While the traditional if-else statement produced:

```
IL_0000: ldstr "test2"
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: ldstr "test2"
IL_000c: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
IL_0011: brfalse IL_001d

IL_0016: ldc.i4.1
IL_0017: stloc.1
IL_0018: br IL_001f

IL_001d: ldc.i4.0
IL_001e: stloc.1

IL_001f: ldloc.1
IL_0020: ret
IL_0013: ret
```

It appears that in my case the Mono compiler created several subroutines and manages a stack of calls in order to handle the if-else.

That being said, if your boolean operation becomes any more complex, then for readability's sake, in a professional development environment, I would at least change it to:

```
if (/*complex boolean operation*/)
    // set state in case of true evaluation
else
    // set state in case of false evaluation
```

Without further context I can't provide you with a better solution.

Comment: As I have written under another answer, the difference in IL may not mean anything. The JIT compiler can and most likely will eliminate any difference. I'd also like to object to your last point: If the condition is that complex, it is hard to read *regardless* how what you do with it. Solving that problem by extracting subexpressions into aptly-named variables improves readability in either case.

Comment: I tend to agree on both of your points - a complex boolean expression needs to be rethought altogether most likely - Steve McConnell in Code Complete suggests placing such complexity into its own method. At any rate my thoughts were simply that - thoughts, well or not. I hope that they provided some input that was inspiring either in the positive or in the negative.

Answer (score -4):

At the risk of being downvoted into oblivion, I would say use the long form because of clarity and maintainability. In the example given, the difference is small. But getting in the habit of writing "clever" one-liners will just make it more difficult for anyone else to maintain your code.

Comment: Aaargh! A boolean expression is not "clever"; it's programming 101! Here, an even clearer longer form for you: `if (cond == true) { return true == true; } else if (cond == false) { return true == false; } else { return FILE_NOT_FOUND; }`. It's longer, so it must be clearer!